# Best Javascript library for scrolling/swiping (iPhone/iPad)

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, mobile

I am currently developing a web app targeting primarily iOS devices (but possibly Android devices later). I am looking for the best solution to allow the user to scroll a div of my web app in a iOS fashion way (elastic/bounce effect), + the possibility to swipe the page left/right in a caroussel fashion.

I have tried a few libraries and found nothing that I really like. I currently use touchscroll for the scrolling, and skinskers touchSwipe for the swiping but both seem to conflict and I would like a all in one solution.

Any help from people having experienced the problem would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm partial to Sencha Touch - http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/. Their [Kitchen Sink](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/) demo is a great sampling of the functionality of the library.

Comment: I don't want a complete framework but just a javascript library that provides swiping and scrolling.

Comment: @Moystard, It appears that this is your best bet ;-)

Comment: I accepted your answer as it could help people but I decided to go with jQuery/iScroll to do the job and it works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried iScroll, Scrollability, our played around with the native -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch and overflow:scroll features for iOS5? I think all of these options are superior to TouchScroll.